# Breast feeding in Iran

Tags: legal, local-customs, culture, children, iran

We are considering a trip to Iran with a 5-month old. What is the local attitude to breast-feeding in public places? Is it legal? Are there any severe consequences? Do you need to use some special cover, etc.?

Comment: It's definitely not a illegal, but bearing the Iranian culture in mind, it'll be awkward. There are public places in Iran like mosques where there are rooms praying rooms meant only for women. You'll have complete privacy there.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As an Iranian I can tell you that breast-feeding in public is NOT a crime (at least in Iran) and you don't need to expect any severe consequences for this. Mothers do feed their children here whenever/wherever needed and it's none of anybody's business to question them why they are feeding their children. **It's however usually a good practice for breasts to be revealed the least possible while feeding the baby (maybe covered under the scarf)**. You are a foreigner and would be of more attraction to people here as foreigners usually are.

Have a nice trip!

***Update:***

I asked a lawyer about this to double-check. There is nothing mentioned in law to prohibit breast-feeding in public. Which means this act is not a crime unless interpreted contrary to Islamic rules. According to Islamic rules on the other hand, every action is permitted in case of emergency e.g. one is allowed to steal something to eat if dying from hunger. Therefore it's concluded that breast-feeding is always permitted because if the baby is not fed s/he will god-forbid die! And this is considered an absolute case of emergency.

Answer (score 6):

Breast-feeding in public is NOT a crime. Iranians, like other humans in the world, feed their children and understand it. Due to beliefs of their region, maybe they use some material like a scarf. Women's dress code in Iran includes *Manto* that is the same as your spring coat. A woman can use it as a cover, but is not necessary for travelers. Iranians are so hospitable. I'm sure you will enjoy your time in Iran.

Answer (score 4):

Yes of course it is "legal",you can see young or middle aged mothers sitting in parks and streets, taking her breast out of their shirt and putting it in a baby mouth, no matter what age she/he is, new born to 5 or 6 years. Don't worry, come here and enjoy sight-seeing as well as breastfeed your baby, but do not forget to wear a scarf around your head, not wearing ""roo sary"" is illegal, so be careful. Have a nice trip.